# How does promise.all work?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I started diggin' in promises and found interesting Promise.all.

It is stated in MDN that

> The Promise.all(iterable) method returns a promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved.

Which basically means that set promises resolve after and if all promises in argument list have been resolved. I tried to implement it. I made simply promise ajax call.

```js
var get = function(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        var xhtml=new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhtml.open("GET",url);
        xhtml.responseType = 'blob';
        xhtml.onload = function() {
            if(xhtml.status==200){
                resolve(xhtml.response);
            } else {
                reject(Error("Error"+statusText));
            }
        }
        xhtml.send();
    });

}

get("one.jpg").then(function(response){
    var blob = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);
    var img = document.createElement("img");

    console.log("Success"+response);

    img.src = blob;

    document.body.appendChild(img);
});
```

Which works fine. But after I tried to add Promise.all it threw an error.

```
Promise.all(get).then(function(response){alert("done")});
```

this as i said threw an error " Argument 1 of Promise.all can't be converted to a sequence." 
So I assume i didn't get the meaning of promise.all.
How does it work?

Comment: `get` is a function; `Promise.all()` takes an array of promise objects

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Promise.all` takes an array (or any iterable) of promises and fulfills when all of them fulfill or rejects when one of them rejects. I think it's easier to understand if we implement it and understand why we need it.

A common use case might be to wait for the window to load and for the server to return data in order to run some code:

```
// a function that returns a promise for when the document is ready.
function windowReady(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
         window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', resolve);
    }); 
}

// function that returns a promise for some data
function getData(){
    return fetch("/").then(function(r){ return r.json() });
}
```

Now, we want both of them to execute *at the same time* and then get the result. There are two items here but there could have easily been 5 things to wait for, or 100. So we use `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all([windowReady(), getData()]).then(function(results){
     // results[1] is the data, it's all in an array.
});
```

Let's see how we can implement it:

```
function all(iterable){ // take an iterable 
  // `all` returns a promise.  
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ 
    let counter = 0; // start with 0 things to wait for
    let results = [], i = 0;
    for(let p of iterable){
        let current = i;
        counter++; // increase the counter 
        Promise.resolve(p).then(function(res){ // treat p as a promise, when it is ready: 
          results[i] = res; // keep the current result
          if(counter === 0) resolve(results) // we're done
        }, reject); // we reject on ANY error
       i++; // progress counter for results array
    }
  });
}
```

Or, in even more ES6ness:

```
let all = iterable => new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  let arr = [...iterable], c = arr.length, results = [];
  arr.map(Promise.resolve, Promise).
      map((p, i) => p.then(v => { 
        r[i] = v;
        if(--c === 0) resolve(r);
      } , reject));
});
```

Comment: Interessting explanation , thanks!. But im not sure if i got few things. 1)Here
 Promise.resolve(p).then(function(res) "treat p  as a promise" , i assume that non prosime would be passed here. Which mean argument in then callback would be returned p , but what if we passed promise there? what would be passed to then? also 2) in  windowReady you passed resolve as an function into eventListener without argument, im not sure what you wanted to tell with that. Thanks for answer!

Comment: Could someone explain what is going on here with this line of code from your example: let results = [], i;

When I test that in my console 'results' is assigned an empty array and 'i' becomes undefined. When you try to use the ++ operator on undefined it becomes NaN. What is going on??

Comment: @jhaubrich.com this is 6 years old so your guess is as good as mine but probably just missing a `i = 0` ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum So you are saying the author meant to initialize i to equal 0, but instead he accidentally initialized it to undefined in this example?

Comment: @jhaubrich.com I am the author - I am saying I do not remember :D I've made an edit initializing it to 0 - that's _probably_ what I meant.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I thought but just wanted to make sure there I wasn't missing something.

Comment: There's a couple errors in this code. you probably need to change ```if(counter === 0)``` to ```if(--counter === 0)``` and r[i] should be results[i]

Answer (score 4):

Your `get` function returns a `Promise`. You are just passing a reference to the `get` function. You have to pass an array of `Promises`

```
Promise.all([get("one.jpg")]).then(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR:**

`Promise.all` is a Javascript method that takes an iterable (e.g. `Array`) of promises as an argument and returns a single promise when **all** the promises in the iterable argument have been resolved (or when iterable argument contains no promises). It resolves with an array of the resolved values and rejects with a single value of the first rejected Promise.

### Example:

```js
var promise1 = Promise.resolve(5);
var promise2 = Math.random() > 0.5? 1 : Promise.reject(1); // either resolves or rejects
var promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('foo'), 1000);
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((val) => {
  console.log(val);
}).catch((val) => {
  console.log(val);
});
```

In the above example 3 Promises are passed into the `Promise.all` function as an array. Promise 1 and 3 always resolve. Promise 2 either resolves or rejects based on the random Nr generator. This Promise.all method then returns a resolved or rejected Promise based on the random Nr generator.

Then the `then()` method and the `catch()` method can be called on this promise which is returned from `Promise.all`. The `then()` method gets an array of all the resolved values, `[5, 1, 'foo']` in this case. The `catch()` method gets the value of the first rejected Promise, `1` in this example.

### When to use:

This method is very usefull when you want to execute **multiple** async operations and need to something with the results after the async operations. When using `Promise.all` all promises can be processed at the same time while still getting to operate on all the incoming data.

For example, when we need to get information using multiple AJAX requests and combine the data to something useful. It is essential to wait for all the data to be available otherwise we would try to combine non existing data which would lead to problems.

Answer (score 0):

The Promise.all(iterables) function returns a single Promise.Here we provide multiple Promises as argument. Promise.all(iterables) function returns promise only when all the promises (argument) have resolved.
It rejects when first promise argument reject.

```
var promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var promise2 = 42;
var promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
// expected output: Array [3, 42, "foo"]
});
```

Syntax:

Promise.all(func1, func2 [,funcN])

Parameters:

Read more at - https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/An-Introduction-To-Promise.all-Function

Disclaimer: I work for oodles technologies