# Promise Chaining and .then/.catch statements

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

The following code is taken from the last task of https://javascript.info/promise-api.

When I run the following, I am unable to get the output to match the alerts that the comments indicate. I assume that I am missing somethign with the catch statements, but I do not understand where I am going wrong. I appreciate any help!

```
// the whole promise chain fails with an error here
// change that:
// make errors appear as members of the results array

let urls = [
  'https://api.github.com/users/iliakan',
  // this URL is HTML page, it's invalid JSON, so response.json() fails
  '/',
  // this URL is invalid, so fetch fails
  'http://no-such-url'
];

// Fix it:
Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url).catch(err=>err)))
  .then(responses => Promise.all(
    responses.map(r => r.json().catch(err=>err))
  ))
  // Demo output (no need to change):
  .then(results => {
    alert(results[0].name); // Ilya Kantor
    alert(results[1]); // SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    alert(results[2]); // TypeError: failed to fetch (text may vary)
  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does promise.all work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31299231/how-does-promise-all-work)

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: I am not getting any error, but no output is showing at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do get an error from your code. In Firefox, for example, it will say `TypeError: r.json is not a function` in the developer console. (I see you're using `alert()` so you might not be familiar with the developer console and `console.log()` available in browsers. If this is so, I'd suggest looking in to them as the information they provide can be invaluable.)

The problem is that, in `r.json()`, `r` is either a response object or an exception object due to the earlier, first `.catch(err=>err)`. Since exception objects do not have a `json` property, it throws its own exception. That exception isn't caught because there's no `try/catch` for it and `.catch()` is only useable on promises.

You could do something like this to check for and pass along an initial exception:

```
responses.map(r => r.json ? r.json().catch(err=>err) : r)
```

Comment: That makes sense, and thank you for clarifying my thoughts! I knew that it had something to do with the fact that the first .catch() statement treated exceptions like a regular object, but .json() would not know how to handle them. However, I was somewhat off the mark, because I was not sure what behavior it would exhibit exactly. Thank you for your insight @Ouroborus!

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this doesn't work is because in the first `.catch(err=>err)` statement, it is treating errors like a standard (successful) result. Then, any faulty data from fetch is called into the next Promise.all statement as it is treated as a good result, and thus r.json() will not know what to do with any faulty data (which is from fetch('/').