# Understand promises in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, es6-promise

I just starts to understand promises. I know you can use the following to handle `d3.csv('https://url.com').then(d => handle(d))` However, I came across the example below, which I'm having a hard time to understand what each part does. Can someone explain?

EDIT:
I understand `Promise.all` does "pass an array of promises and only fires a function once all those promises have been resolved or one of them has been rejected. "

This is example taken from `Listing 7.4. The adjacency matrix function` in D3.Js in Action.

```js
var PromiseWrapper = d => new Promise(resolve => d3.csv(d, p => resolve(p))); // part1


      Promise
        .all([
          PromiseWrapper("../data/nodelist.csv"),
          PromiseWrapper("../data/edgelist.csv")
        ]) //part2
        .then(resolve => {
          createAdjacencyMatrix(resolve[0], resolve[1]);
        }); //part3
```

EDIT:
To incorporate d3v5 `d3-fetch`, is the following correct?

```js
//ver1
const promise1 = d3.csv('../data/nodelist.csv')
const promise2 = d3.csv('../data/nodelist.csv')

Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(resolve => 
   createAdjacencyMatrix(resolve[0], resolve[1]));
```

Or I need to do the following?

```js
//ver2
const promise1 = d3.csv('../data/nodelist.csv').then(d => d)
const promise2 = d3.csv('../data/nodelist.csv').then(d => d) 

Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(resolve => 
   createAdjacencyMatrix(resolve[0], resolve[1]));
```

What are the difference between `ver1` and `ver2`?

Comment: The `PromiseWrapper` returns a new promise that processes a csv file and resolves with its value, it appears to just be a helper function to make the code cleaner. `Promise.all` takes an array of promises then passes the resolved data to `then` as an array.
So this snippet would process all csv files and then create an adjacency matrix with the resulting data.
MDN has some good info on what `all` does if you would like some further reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does promise.all work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31299231/how-does-promise-all-work)

Comment: @CharlieH I updated my question. Focus of this question might be a bit different to the link.

Comment: The `PromiseWrapper` function is completely unnecessary, because d3.csv **already** returns a promise. That being said, from your 3 snippets in the question, only the "ver1" is correct.

Comment: The proposed duplicate target is not adequate, because d3.csv plays a fundamental role in this question here.

Answer (score 0):

The `PromiseWrapper("../data/nodelist.csv")` returns a promise.

[Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) takes all these promises in an array and returns a single promise which will be resolved when ALL the promises are resolved.

```js
var promise1 = new Promise(resolve => {
   setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000) });
   
 var promise2 = new Promise(resolve => {
   setTimeout(() => resolve(), 5000) });
   
   
 Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(() => {
    console.log('All promises are resolved');
 })
```