# Can I use a for loop to create an array of promises?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, axios

In my Vue application, I'm using a for loop to iterate over an array of strings. Axios sends each element in the array to the API and receives the result of the call, which I append to an array. Unfortunately, the responses don't always arrive in the right order. Is there a way that I can track individual Axios requests so I can unscramble the responses later?

Edit: As per goto1’s comment below I have started using Promise.all() but I am receiving an error. The code has been changed to reflect this. Is the usage of the for loop creating this error?

Here's the code I have:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      a: "",
      b: "Waiting...",
      word: "",
      array: [],
      promises: [],
      abc: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    axi: function (p) {
      //create array of promises
      for (var x = 0; x < this.word.length; x++) {
        this.promises.push(axios.get("https://googledictionaryapi.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/?define=" + this.word[x]));

      }

      //promise.all
      Promise.all(this.promises)
    },

    //returns api call result for each item
    multi: function () {

      //this.a could be a string like “the quick brown fox”
      var word = this.a;

      //this.word turns into an array: ["the","quick","brown","fox"]
      this.word = word.match(/\b(\w+)\b/g);



      //each string is sent to the API
      this.axi().then((response) => {
          var r = response;

          //I am hoping to get something like [“the”, "quick", "brown", "fox"]

          console.log(r);

        })

        //ignore rest of code from here
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log("Error! Could not reach the API. " + error);

        });




    },
    //handles other stuff
    getA: function () {
      if (this.a === "") {
        this.b = "Waiting...";
      }

      this.b = "Retrieving...";
      //for another thing
      this.array = [];
      this.abc = [];
      this.word = [];
      //function call
      this.multi();

    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Use something like `Promise.all()` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31299231/how-does-promise-all-work

Comment: `return Promise.all(...)`. Also `word` is undefined in `this.word = word.match(/\b(\w+)\b/g)`